# How to get nodes in a particular city? [Open Street Maps - Overpass API / Nominatim]

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, overpass-api, search

I wish to get nodes that belong to a particular city. I tried doing a radius search around the latitude and longitude of the city but that is just an approximation. Moreover the radius varies from one city to another. Is there a good way to do this using Open Street Maps?

Comment: you need the bounding box of the city see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#All_data_in_a_bounding_box

Answer (score 4):

When there is a boundary relation for that city area (like political boundaries) you can use its name for a query via overpass-api or overpass-turbo.

So first find out about any good boundary relation within the OSM data:
go to http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org and try to find a boundary relation for your city ... for example type "Buxtehude" in its search box there (Buxtehude is a small city in the north of Germany) ... see the results and its detail links.

With that background knowledge vidit http://overpass-turbo.eu and use its wizard modus: Try "shop=* in Buxtehude" there ... without ""

Thus you can limit any query via overpass-api or overpass-turbo (or even QuickOSM-Plugin in QGIS) to any city area as long as we have boundaries for that in the OSM data.

Please refer to the documentation of overpass-api and overpass turbo at wiki.osm.org

If you get stuck about a boundary is present or not, tell us the name of the city we can use for testing purposes.

Tell us here about success or failure in general.

Comment: I found another solution to this problem - using area queries. Eg.
`[out:json];
area[name = "New York"];
node(area)[amenity=bar];
out;`

However the issue with this is that if I query the following:

`[out:json];
area[name = "New York"];
(
 node(area)[amenity=bar];
 node(area)[amenity=restaurant];
);
out;`

The output includes only the first amenity, i.e. 'bar' even though there's a union. Any ideas?

Comment: I can confirm that your last query only returns bars, but no restaurants ... I have no knowledge whether there is an error in that query or a bug in overpass-api ... Tried to enter "amenity=bar or amenity=restaurent in XXX" in overpass-turbo-Wizard and it also gives only the bars and not the restaurants!!! Any experts here??????

Comment: @stephan75: I think you simply made a typo, it's restaurant, not restaurent. The same user created a new question for this topic: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151702/how-to-use-union-in-area-queries-ql-xml-with-overpass-api-openstreetmaps