# Querying OpenStreetMap for tags does not return ways or relations?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I try to obtain all ways/nodes/relations with a special tag from OpenStreetMap. I use the following code to receive all hotels (in a small town in Austria):

```
//[out:csv(name, "addr:street", "addr:city")][timeout:25];
area
  [boundary=administrative]
  ["name"="Fügen"];
out body;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building=* and name=*”
  node["tourism"="hotel"](area);
  way["building"]["tourism"="hotel"](area);
  relation["building"]["tourism"="hotel"](area);
);
// print results
out body;
```

You may access the [result via Overpass](http://overpass-turbo.eu/map.html?Q=%0A%0A%2F%2F[out%3Acsv%28name%2C%20%22addr%3Astreet%22%2C%20%22addr%3Acity%22%29][timeout%3A25]%3B%0Aarea%0A%20%20[boundary%3Dadministrative]%0A%20%20[%22name%22%3D%22F%C3%BCgen%22]%3B%0Aout%20body%3B%0A%2F%2F%20gather%20results%0A%28%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20query%20part%20for%3A%20%E2%80%9Cbuilding%3D*%20and%20name%3D*%E2%80%9D%0A%20%20node[%22tourism%22%3D%22hotel%22]%28area%29%3B%0A%20%20way[%22building%22][%22tourism%22%3D%22hotel%22]%28area%29%3B%0A%20%20relation[%22building%22][%22tourism%22%3D%22hotel%22]%28area%29%3B%0A%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20print%20results%0Aout%20body%3B). However, this result gives me only the nodes. Ways [like #89729697](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/89729697) also having the `tourism = hotel` tag are not returned.

How do I also query for the ways and relations having the tag I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a quite common mistake. Please [refer to this post for a more comprehensive explanation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151702/how-to-use-union-in-area-queries-ql-xml-with-overpass-api-openstreetmaps/151706#151706).

You need to store the area in a dedicated input set (here: myarea), otherwise the first statement inside the union statement will overwrite your area Fügen and the way/relation statement no longer have an area to work on.

Here's how your query should look like: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/dix

```c
area
  [boundary=administrative]
  ["name"="Fügen"]->.myarea;

(
  node["tourism"="hotel"](area.myarea);
  way["building"]["tourism"="hotel"](area.myarea);
  relation["building"]["tourism"="hotel"](area.myarea);
);

out geom;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your fast answer! I was thinking on this issue quite a long time ;)