# Overpass turbo OSM: how to combine and unite several filters?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I would like to request all service companies in specified area using the Overpass API.

The following [request](https://osm.li/AiV) delivers only the result of the first filter `node[shop](area);` and does not unify with the second filter for restaurants and bars.

```
area[name="Kriens"];
(
node[shop](area);
node["amenity"~"^(restaurant|bar|fast_food|cafe)$"](area);
);  
out center;
```

I try to accomplish a Union of filters as [described in the documentation](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/criteria/union.html). What's wrong with the given filter?

By-the-way: What filter-set would you recommend retrieving all publically accessible commercial services (shops, bars, restaurant etc. but not schools, libraries etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result of your `area()` call in a *named set* first. Without a named set, the results are stored in the *default set*. This default set gets overwritten by your `node[shop](area);` query.

As a solution, store the result in a named set. Then perform your queries on this named set:

```
area[name="Kriens"]->.foo;
(
    node[shop](area.foo);
    node["amenity"~"^(restaurant|bar|fast_food|cafe)$"](area.foo);
);  
out center;
```

I'm not an expert on Overpass API. I hope my explanations are correct.

Comment: Your explanation is fine, see my explanation here for the same question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151702/how-to-use-union-in-area-queries-ql-xml-with-overpass-api-openstreetmaps/151706#151706